# Kohana auth login

Tags: authentication, kohana-3.2

I'm trying to user kohana auth module, but i get the error:
' Call to undefined method Model_User::unique_key()'

i user the code:

```
$auth = Auth::instance();
    if ($auth->login($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']))
    {
        echo 'hello, '.$auth->$_POST['username'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'login failed!';
    }
```

This happends when the email and password are ok.
Do you know what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The error you are receiving seems to be because you do not have a config file setup for auth. You should have a file located at /application/config/auth.php. Here is an example of mine:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');

return array(

    'driver'       => 'ORM',
    'hash_method'  => 'sha256',
    'hash_key'     => 'Somebiglonghaskeyofmixedcharacters102345567709',
    'lifetime'     => 1209600,
    'session_type' => Session::$default,
    'session_key'  => 'auth_user',

    // Username/password combinations for the Auth File driver
    'users' => array(
        // 'admin' => 'b3154acf3a344170077d11bdb5fff31532f679a1919e716a02',
    ),
);
```

My config file causes auth to use the database to store users. See the documentation on how to setup your database or you can use file authentication.

Once you get your config working, you can log in a user like this:

```
$user = Auth::instance()->login($this->request->post('username'), $this->request->post('password'), $remember);
```

I also find it useful to create my own user model in application/classes/model/user.php. Here is an example of mine:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');
class Model_User extends ORM {

/**
 * A user has many tokens and roles
 *
 * @var array Relationhips
 */
protected $_has_many = array(
    'user_tokens' => array('model' => 'user_token'),
    'roles'       => array('model' => 'role', 'through' => 'roles_users'),
);

/**
 * Rules for the user model. Because the password is _always_ a hash
 * when it's set,you need to run an additional not_empty rule in your controller
 * to make sure you didn't hash an empty string. The password rules
 * should be enforced outside the model or with a model helper method.
 *
 * @return array Rules
 */
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        'username' => array(
            array('not_empty'),
            array('max_length', array(':value', 32)),
            array(array($this, 'unique'), array('username', ':value')),
            array('regex', array(':value', '/^[a-z][a-z0-9]+$/i')),
        ),
        'email' => array(
            array('not_empty'),
            array('email'),
            array(array($this, 'unique'), array('email', ':value')),
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Filters to run when data is set in this model. The password filter
 * automatically hashes the password when it's set in the model.
 *
 * @return array Filters
 */
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'password' => array(
            array(array(Auth::instance(), 'hash'))
        )
    );
}

/**
 * Labels for fields in this model
 *
 * @return array Labels
 */
public function labels()
{
    return array();
}

/**
 * Complete the login for a user by incrementing the logins and saving login timestamp
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function complete_login()
{
    if ($this->_loaded)
    {
        // Update the number of logins
        $this->logins = new Database_Expression('logins + 1');

        // Set the last login date
        $this->last_login = time();

        // Save the user
        $this->update();
    }
}

/**
 * Tests if a unique key value exists in the database.
 *
 * @param   mixed    the value to test
 * @param   string   field name
 * @return  boolean
 */
public function unique_key_exists($value, $field = NULL)
{
    if ($field === NULL)
    {
        // Automatically determine field by looking at the value
        $field = $this->unique_key($value);
    }

    return (bool) DB::select(array('COUNT("*")', 'total_count'))
        ->from($this->_table_name)
        ->where($field, '=', $value)
        ->where($this->_primary_key, '!=', $this->pk())
        ->execute($this->_db)
        ->get('total_count');
}

/**
 * Allows a model use both email and username as unique identifiers for login
 *
 * @param   string  unique value
 * @return  string  field name
 */
public function unique_key($value)
{
    return Valid::email($value) ? 'email' : 'username';
}

/**
 * Password validation for plain passwords.
 *
 * @param array $values
 * @return Validation
 */
public static function get_password_validation($values)
{
    return Validation::factory($values)
        ->rule('password', 'min_length', array(':value', 8))
        ->rule('password_confirm', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('password_confirm', 'min_length', array(':value', 8))
        ->rule('password_confirm', 'matches', array(':validation', 'password', ':field'));
}

/**
 * Create a new user
 *
 * Example usage:
 * ~~~
 * $user = ORM::factory('user')->create_user($_POST, array(
 *  'username',
 *  'password',
 *  'email',
 * );
 * ~~~
 *
 * @param array $values
 * @param array $expected
 * @throws ORM_Validation_Exception
 */
public function create_user($values, $expected)
{
    // Validation for passwords
    $extra_validation = Model_User::get_password_validation($values)
        ->rule('password', 'not_empty');

    return $this->values($values, $expected)->create($extra_validation);
}

/**
 * Update an existing user
 *
 * [!!] We make the assumption that if a user does not supply a password, that they do not wish to update their password.
 *
 * Example usage:
 * ~~~
 * $user = ORM::factory('user')
 *  ->where('username', '=', 'kiall')
 *  ->find()
 *  ->update_user($_POST, array(
 *      'username',
 *      'password',
 *      'email',
 *  );
 * ~~~
 *
 * @param array $values
 * @param array $expected
 * @throws ORM_Validation_Exception
 */
public function update_user($values, $expected = NULL)
{
    if (empty($values['password']))
    {
        unset($values['password'], $values['password_confirm']);
    }

    // Validation for passwords
    $extra_validation = Model_User::get_password_validation($values);

    return $this->values($values, $expected)->update($extra_validation);
}
} // End Auth User Model
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this and fixed it by making my model extend `Model_Auth_User`.